# Can't configure Feign Client timeouts

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm using Feign Client with disabled Load Balancer

```
@FeignClient(name = "my-client", url = "${myHost}", configuration = ClientContext.class)
```

So, all ribbon properties are ignored.
I'm trying to set custom timeouts by different ways, but Feign ignores all them and throws TimeoutException after 60 seconds.
Ways I tried to use:
in ClientContext:
1)

```
@Value("${feign.connectTimeout:10000}")
private int connectTimeout;

@Value("${feign.readTimeOut:300000}")
private int readTimeout;

@Bean
public Request.Options options() {
    return new Request.Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout);
}
```

2)

```
@Bean
public Request.Options options() {
    return new Request.Options(10_000, 300_000);
}
```

in bootstrap.properties file:
1)

```
feign.client.default.connect-timeout=10000
feign.client.default.read-timeout=300000
```

2)

```
feign.client.default.config.connect-timeout=10000
feign.client.default.config.read-timeout=300000
```

3)

```
feign.client.default.connectTimeout=10000
feign.client.default.readTimeout=300000
```

4)

```
feign.client.default.config.connectTimeout=10000
feign.client.default.config.readTimeout=300000
```

Error stack trace is:

```
Error Message: feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://myrequest...
Stacktrace: 
feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67)
feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:10)
feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
```

Can you suggest me right configuration or found what is wrong in code blocks above?

Comment: You probably use hystrix with feign and its timeout is default 1s.

Comment: I've added stack trace later. There aren't any hystrix mention. Can it be because of hystrix anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right solution was

```
@Value("${feign.connectTimeout:10000}")
private int connectTimeout;

@Value("${feign.readTimeOut:300000}")
private int readTimeout;

@Bean
public Request.Options options() {
    return new Request.Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout);
}
```

and add to .properties file this one `payer-service-client.feign.hystrix.enabled=false`

Answer (score 2):

There is also a way to do this with configuration only.

Add to your `application.yml`:

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      my-client:
        connectTimeout: 10000
        readTimeout: 300000
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75526697/6588493) you need to put only

> `spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.readTimeout=300000`
> `spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.default.connect-timeout=10000`

in your `application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misplacing the `default` attribute.

The correct way of using the default timeout properties are :

```
feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout=xxxx
feign.client.config.default.readTimeout=xxxx
```

These will be applicable for all the feign clients. If you want to apply it to a specific client you can refer to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For open-feign you need

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          default:
            readTimeout: 5000
            connectTimeout: 5000
```